# Why can I not replicate this ValueError interactively?

Tags: python, python-requests, robotframework

I am writing Robot Framework tests using the [RequestsLibrary](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests), which is itself built on the `requests` module.

When I attempt to use the `Create Session` keyword with a `headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` parameter, I get a `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Example of keyword call:

```
Suite Setup | Create Session | api_session | www.foo.com | verify=True | headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

If I do what that keyword is doing interactively, I cannot reproduce:

```
$ python
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> print(s.headers)
{'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.9.1'}
>>> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
>>> s.headers.update(headers)
>>> print(s.headers)
{'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.9.1'}
```

So for some reason `s.headers.update(headers)` throws the `ValueError` only when I am running in the context of a RobotFramework test.  I have logged the value of `headers` just before calling `s.headers.update(headers)` in the Robot tests, and I see what I would expect: `{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`, which leaves me stumped.

So what is causing the error? More generally, since many people don't have experience with Robot Framework, how could I make the above interactive session throw the same error?

Comment: You can just do `raise ValueError("hello")` if that's what you are asking.

Comment: please show exactly how you are calling the keyword.

Comment: @steven No, I don't just want to throw the error manually, I want to cause Python to throw the error - I need to understand what is happening in order to fix it.  Asked another way - how can calling dictfoo.update(dictbar) throw this value error?

Comment: added example of keyword call

Comment: that keyword is **not** doing what you think it is doing, `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` is very explicit whatever it is unpacking it is expecting `1` more of.

Comment: This IS a duplicate of that, you are right. I didn't see quotes in the log, so I assumed it was actually a dictionary.